# Custom destination for NavigationLink inside ForEach

Tags: swiftui

Is there a way to do the following:

I have ForEach loop, and NavigationLink inside. I want when user click for example on "Notification" to show Notification View, but please keep in mind, that Every View is different so I can't Create for example DetailView.

```
struct SettingSectionView: View {
    @ObservedObject var settingsVM: SettingsViewModel
    var itemsToIterate: [Setting]
    var sectionTitle: String
  
    var body: some View {
        VStack(alignment:.leading, spacing:10){
            Text(sectionTitle)
                .font(.custom("Ubuntu-Medium", size: 19))
                .padding(.vertical, 15)
            
            
            ForEach(itemsToIterate) { item in
                if item.shouldShowNavigationLink{
                    NavigationLink(destination: item.title, label: {
                        ZStack(alignment: .leading){
                            RoundedRectangle(cornerRadius: 5)
                                .fill(Color.gray.opacity(0.1))
                                .frame(height:50)
                                .overlay(
                                    RoundedRectangle(cornerRadius: 5)
                                        .stroke(Color.gray.opacity(0.3), lineWidth:1)
                                )
                            HStack{
                                Text(item.title)
                                    .font(.custom("Ubuntu-Regular", size: 14))
                                
                                Spacer()
                                if item.isToggle{
                                    Toggle(isOn: $settingsVM.isToggle){
                                        
                                    }
                                }
                                if item.chevronPhoto{
                                    Image(systemName: "chevron.right")
                                        .font(.system(size:12))
                                }
                            }.padding(.horizontal, 10)
                        }
                    })
                } else {
                    ZStack(alignment: .leading){
                        RoundedRectangle(cornerRadius: 5)
                            .fill(Color.gray.opacity(0.1))
                            .frame(height:50)
                            .overlay(
                                RoundedRectangle(cornerRadius: 5)
                                    .stroke(Color.gray.opacity(0.3), lineWidth:1)
                            )
                        HStack{
                            Text(item.title)
                                .font(.custom("Ubuntu-Regular", size: 14))
                            
                            Spacer()
                            if item.isToggle{
                                Toggle(isOn: $settingsVM.isToggle){
                                    
                                }
                            }
                            if item.chevronPhoto{
                                Image(systemName: "chevron.right")
                                    .font(.system(size:12))
                            }
                        }.padding(.horizontal, 10)
                    }
                }
            }.scrollContentBackground(.hidden)
            
        }
        .foregroundColor(.black)
    }
}
```

The Settings model is:

```
struct Setting: Identifiable, Hashable {
    var id: UUID = UUID()
    var title: String
    var isToggle: Bool
    var chevronPhoto: Bool
    var shouldShowNavigationLink: Bool
}
```

And ViewModel is:

```
class SettingsViewModel: ObservableObject {
     let accountValue: [Setting] = [
        Setting(title:"Account", isToggle: false, chevronPhoto: true, shouldShowNavigationLink:true),
        Setting(title:"Profile", isToggle: false, chevronPhoto: true, shouldShowNavigationLink:true)
    ]
    
}
```

So again, what I want to achieve, if user click on Notification, I want to lead him on NotificationView() if user click on Account I want to lead him on AccountView()

Answer (score 0):

I did it!

I added in Setting model

```
var destination: AnyView
```